# How can I make the Google Maps TERRAIN map type yellow instead of green?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I really like the Terrain map type for Google Maps.

But instead of the default background be green for the map, how can I make the color yellow?

Comment: @JessicaD: Do you have any reference to the type of yellow map you have in mind? The Google Maps terrain isn't specifically green. It is colour-coded. The desert-regions are yellow in fact: http://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&ll=28.459033,14.545898&spn=33.046986,60.424805&t=p&z=5

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a yellow tinted version of the Terrain [map type](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#MapTypeId).  You are able to build custom tilesets or overlays for Google Maps, but if you want to have access to the global set of tiles that Google Maps provides, you are limited to the standard map tile types:

- **HYBRID** - This map type displays a transparent layer of major streets on satellite images.
- **ROADMAP** - This map type displays a normal street map.
- **SATELLITE** - This map type displays satellite images.
- **TERRAIN** - This map type displays maps with physical features such as terrain and vegetation.

I toyed with the idea of filtering the map through a semi transparent image (as a map overlay) or a floating div with a yellow tint, but I think ultimately this won't get the affect you are after. If I get a chance I'll  try this out and let you know how it goes.